# Android - Ripple and shadow on view?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

Is it possible to have a ripple effect on a view at the same time as you have a dropdown shadow? I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The issue I'm having is getting them both into one drawable. I can't get the shadow to show

Comment: You'd have to provide any details for anybody to be able to help you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please refer to the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and when needed, how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can try to help you with a problem. You're often expected to do your own homework and research before asking a question.